# How to search excel workbooks in folders, and subfolders for a specific string of text in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a huge folder that has many folders inside of many folders that contain Excel workbooks. I'd like to have a user input to ask for a string of numbers (Ex: 405599) and search through every folder, subfolder, workbook, sheet and provide a link or location of that file. This is code currently, But it seems to get stuck searching the very first row of the first document and then crashes.

[image]

```html
   Public WS As Worksheet
Sub SearchWKBooksSubFolders(Optional Folderpath As Variant, Optional Str As Variant)
Dim myfolder As String
Dim a As Single
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Single
Dim Folders() As String
Dim Folder As Variant
ReDim Folders(0)
If IsMissing(Folderpath) Then
Set WS = Sheets.Add
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
Str = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Search string:", Title:="Search all workbooks in a folder", Type:=2)
If Str = "" Then Exit Sub
WS.Range("A1") = "Search string:"
WS.Range("B1") = Str
WS.Range("A2") = "Path:"
WS.Range("B2") = myfolder
WS.Range("A3") = "Folderpath"
WS.Range("B3") = "Workbook"
WS.Range("C3") = "Worksheet"
WS.Range("D3") = "Cell Address"
WS.Range("E3") = "Link"
Folderpath = myfolder
Value = Dir(myfolder, &H1F)
Else
If Right(Folderpath, 2) = "\\" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Value = Dir(Folderpath, &H1F)
End If
Do Until Value = ""
If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
Else
    If GetAttr(Folderpath & Value) = 16 Then
        Folders(UBound(Folders)) = Value
        ReDim Preserve Folders(UBound(Folders) + 1)
    ElseIf (Right(Value, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsm") And Left(Value, 1) <> "~" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Folderpath & Value, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz")
        On Error GoTo 0
        'If there is an error on Workbooks.Open, then wb Is Nothing:
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            Lrow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            WS.Range("A" & Lrow).Value = Value
            WS.Range("B" & Lrow).Value = "Password protected"
        Else
            For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
                'Expand all groups in sheet
                sht.Unprotect

                sht.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8, ColumnLevels:=8
                Set c = sht.Cells.Find(Str, After:=sht.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    firstAddress = c.Address
                    Do
                        Lrow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        WS.Range("A" & Lrow).Value = Folderpath
                        WS.Range("B" & Lrow).Value = Value
                        WS.Range("C" & Lrow).Value = sht.Name
                        WS.Range("D" & Lrow).Value = c.Address
                        WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("E" & Lrow), Address:=Folderpath & Value, SubAddress:= _
                        "'" & sht.Name & "'" & "!" & c.Address, TextToDisplay:="Link"
                        Set c = sht.Cells.FindNext(After:=c)

                    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                End If
            Next sht
            wb.Close False
        End If
    End If
End If
Value = Dir
Loop
For Each Folder In Folders
Call SearchWKBooksSubFolders(Folderpath & Folder & "\", Str)
Next Folder
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: "stuck" as like an infinite loop? Or do you have an error?

Comment: Your possible misuse of `On Error Resume Next` may be masking errors -- it looks like your entire `Else` block is within the `Resume Next` (assuming no error with the `Workbooks.Open` statement. Also, you may want to avoid relying on `ActiveWorkbook`, best to assign to another `Workbook` type object variable and work with that.

Comment: Yeah i left it on for about an hour and a half and it was still on the first document of the first folder/subfolder. No errors.

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm sorry, I don't have a lot of experience with VBA Excel so I'm not sure what changes have to be made from your explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should improve the error handler which was potentially causing problems as it was not properly scoped.

I've changed both the `Find` and `FindNext` to use the `After` argument, without which you may get some unexpected results. Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-findnext-method-excel) (emphasis added):

> After:= The cell after which you want to search. This corresponds to the position of the active cell when a search is done from the user interface. Be aware that After must be a single cell in the range. Remember that the search begins after this cell; the specified cell is not searched until the method wraps back around to this cell. **If this argument is not specified, the search starts after the cell in the upper-left corner of the range.**

Also I'm not sure why you were offseting by `a` in case of error, rather than just using the `LRow` computation. I've made that change also.

Put a Breakpoint on the line below where I note `'##### BREAK here and step through code using F8`, then step through the code line-by-line using <kbd>F8</kbd> to confirm that this method is working correctly. Once you've confirmed, remove the breakpoint and you can allow the code to run to completion.

```
Public WS As Worksheet
Sub SearchWKBooksSubFolders(Optional Folderpath As Variant, Optional Str As Variant)
Dim myfolder As String
Dim a As Single
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Single
Dim Folders() As String
Dim Folder As Variant
ReDim Folders(0)
If IsMissing(Folderpath) Then
    Set WS = Sheets.Add
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
    Str = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Search string:", Title:="Search all workbooks in a folder", Type:=2)
    If Str = "" Then Exit Sub
    WS.Range("A1") = "Search string:"
    WS.Range("B1") = Str
    WS.Range("A2") = "Path:"
    WS.Range("B2") = myfolder
    WS.Range("A3") = "Folderpath"
    WS.Range("B3") = "Workbook"
    WS.Range("C3") = "Worksheet"
    WS.Range("D3") = "Cell Address"
    WS.Range("E3") = "Link"
    Folderpath = myfolder
    Value = Dir(myfolder, &H1F)
Else
    If Right(Folderpath, 2) = "\\" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Value = Dir(Folderpath, &H1F)
End If
Do Until Value = ""
    If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
    Else
        If GetAttr(Folderpath & Value) = 16 Then
            Folders(UBound(Folders)) = Value
            ReDim Preserve Folders(UBound(Folders) + 1)
        ElseIf (Right(Value, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsm") And Left(Value, 1) <> "~" Then Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim wb As Workbook
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Folderpath & Value, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz")
            On Error GoTo 0
            'If there is an error on Workbooks.Open, then wb Is Nothing:
            If wb Is Nothing Then
                Lrow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                WS.Range("A" & Lrow).Value = Value
                WS.Range("B" & Lrow).Value = "Password protected"
            Else
                For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
                    'Expand all groups in sheet
                    sht.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8, ColumnLevels:=8
                    Set c = sht.Cells.Find(Str, After:=sht.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        firstAddress = c.Address
                        Do
                            Lrow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            WS.Range("A" & Lrow).Value = Folderpath
                            WS.Range("B" & Lrow).Value = Value
                            WS.Range("C" & Lrow).Value = sht.Name
                            WS.Range("D" & Lrow).Value = c.Address
                            WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("E" & Lrow), Address:=Folderpath & Value, SubAddress:= _
                            "'" & sht.Name & "'" & "!" & c.Address, TextToDisplay:="Link"
                            Set c = sht.Cells.FindNext(After:=c)

                        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                    End If
                Next sht
                wb.Close False
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Value = Dir
Loop
For Each Folder In Folders
    Call SearchWKBooksSubFolders(Folderpath & Folder & "\", Str)
Next Folder
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

This seems to be working as expected for me:

[image]

On the problem with subfolders, while you're calling this procedure recursively, you're **not** passing the *optional* `Str` argument to the recursive calls. So for the subfolders, the function is searching for empty `Variant` type, which it finds in many, many cells!

Change:

```
SearchWKBooksSubFolders (Folderpath & Folder & "\")
```

To:

```
Call SearchWKBooksSubFolders(Folderpath & Folder & "\", Str)
```