# VBA Excel - search multipe terms in workbooks with values matching to them

Tags: excel, vba

I have the problem as follows:

[image]

I have several workbooks in my directory, in which I want to find them by typing the code. The problem is, that apart from this code I would like to have also the value corresponding to this code. As you see in the image provided, I have the code on the cell A2 and I would like to have the value of this code (cell F2).

So far I used the code from here:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3354-excel-search-multiple-sheets-workbooks.html

which has been tweaked slightly and now looks like this:

```
Sub SearchFolders()
Dim xFso As Object
Dim xFld As Object
Dim xStrSearch As String
Dim xStrPath As String
Dim xStrFile As String
Dim xOut As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xWk As Worksheet
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xFound As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim xStrAddress As String
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim xUpdate As Boolean
Dim xCount As Long
Dim xAWB As Workbook
Dim xAWBStrPath As String
Dim xBol As Boolean
Dim rngValue As Variant
Set xAWB = ActiveWorkbook
xAWBStrPath = xAWB.Path & "\" & xAWB.Name
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
    xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
xStrSearch = InputBox("Please provide the Code")
xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xOut = Worksheets.Add
xRow = 1
With xOut
    .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
    .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
    .Cells(xRow, 3) = "Cell"
    .Cells(xRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
    .Cells(xRow, 5) = "Values corresponding"
    Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
    xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xls*")
    Do While xStrFile <> ""
        xBol = False
        If (xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile) = xAWBStrPath Then
            xBol = True
            Set xWb = xAWB
        Else
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
        End If
        For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
            If xBol And (xWk.Name = .Name) Then
            Else
            Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(xStrSearch)
            Set rng = xFound.EntireRow.Cells("F")
            If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                xStrAddress = xFound.Address
            End If
            Do
                If xFound Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    xCount = xCount + 1
                    xRow = xRow + 1
                    .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                    .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                    .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address
                    .Cells(xRow, 4) = xFound.Value
                    .Cells(xRow, 5) = xWk.Range("F")
                End If
                Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
                rngValue = xFound.EntireRow.Value
            Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
            End If
        Next
        If Not xBol Then
        xWb.Close (False)
        End If
        xStrFile = Dir
    Loop
    .Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
MsgBox xCount & " cells have been found", , "Code calculator"
```

ExitHandler:
Set xOut = Nothing
Set xWk = Nothing
Set xWb = Nothing
Set xFld = Nothing
Set xFso = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
Resume ExitHandler
End Sub

I used these 2 hints:

[Search for a value and return the entire row in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308887/search-for-a-value-and-return-the-entire-row-in-excel)

[How to search excel workbooks in folders, and subfolders for a specific string of text in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807841/how-to-search-excel-workbooks-in-folders-and-subfolders-for-a-specific-string-o)

but I am getting following errors:

**Object variable or with variable not set**

for the following line:

```
 Set rng = xFound.EntireRow.Cells("F")
```

whereas earlier the `rng` has been defined in `Dim rng as Range`

My second error is:

Method 'Range of object' Worksheet failed.

at the line:

```
 .Cells(xRow, 5) = xWk.Range("F")
```

Is there any way of searching for the value across all workbooks in the directory and another value, which matches this value?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer here:

[Hyperlink specific cell under column on VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62660983/hyperlink-specific-cell-under-column-on-vba-code)

Instead of:

```
 .Cells(xRow, 5) = xWk.Range("F")
```

We need to put:

```
 .Cells(xRow, 5).Range("A1").Value = xFound.EntireRow.Range("F1").Value
```

Where the `Range("A1")` in the given worksheet corresponds to the `Range("F1")` in the same workbook.
By placing the `Range("A1")` in the `.Cells(xRow, 5)` we are receiving the final value of `Range("F1")` in this cell.

[image]