# quickly search value for multiple workbooks with specified sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Following the question:

[VBA Excel - search multipe terms in workbooks with values matching to them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74715902/vba-excel-search-multipe-terms-in-workbooks-with-values-matching-to-them/74717006#74717006)

I would like to make a search for multiple workbooks across the directory, but with specified, repeatable sheets.
[image]

The full code:

```
   Sub SearchFolders()

Dim xFso As Object
Dim xFld As Object
Dim xStrSearch As String
Dim xStrPath As String
Dim xStrFile As String
Dim xOut As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xWk As Worksheet
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim xFound As Range
Dim xStrAddress As String
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim xUpdate As Boolean
Dim xCount As Long
Dim xAWB As Workbook
Dim xAWBStrPath As String
Dim xBol As Boolean
Set xAWB = ActiveWorkbook
'Set xWk = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Civils*")
xAWBStrPath = xAWB.Path & "\" & xAWB.Name
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
    xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
'xStrSearch = "1366P"
xStrSearch = InputBox("Please provide the BoM Code")
xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xOut = Worksheets("SUMMARY")
xRow = 1
With xOut
    .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
    .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
    .Cells(xRow, 3) = "Cell"
    .Cells(xRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
    .Cells(xRow, 5) = "Values corresponding"
    Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
    xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xls*")
    Do While xStrFile <> ""
        xBol = False
        If (xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile) = xAWBStrPath Then
            xBol = True
            Set xWb = xAWB
        Else
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
            'Set xWk = Worksheets.Open("Civils Job Order")
        End If
        'For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets("Civils Work Order")
         For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
            If xBol And (xWk.Name = .Name) Then
           'If xBol And (xWk.Name = "Civils Work Order" Or xWk.Name = "Cable Works Order") Then
            Else
            Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(xStrSearch)
            If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                xStrAddress = xFound.Address
            End If
            Do
                If xFound Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    xCount = xCount + 1
                    xRow = xRow + 1
                    .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                    .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                    .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address
                    .Cells(xRow, 4) = xFound.Value
                    .Cells(xRow, 5).Range("A1").Value = xFound.EntireRow.Range("F1").Value
                End If
                Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
            Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
            End If
        Next
        If Not xBol Then
        xWb.Close (False)
        End If
        xStrFile = Dir
    Loop
    .Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
End With
MsgBox xCount & " cells have been found", , "BoM Calculator for VM Greenfield"
ExitHandler:
Set xOut = Nothing
Set xWk = Nothing
Set xWb = Nothing
Set xFld = Nothing
Set xFso = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

There is no error coming in, but the Excel is frozen indefinitely.

Is it some solution for making this kind of search for the specified worksheet names, which occur regularly across all workbooks in the directory?

Comment: `(xWk.Name = "Civils Work Order" And xWk.Name = "Cable Works Order")` Likely `xWk.Name` can't be two values at the same time   Maybe you meant to use `Or` here?

Comment: Even if I apply Or, they still throw all values.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "they still throw all values".  Might be better to add your full current code to the question, so we don't have to flip back and forth between two posts.

Comment: Ok added a full code with all approaches quoted with '

Comment: Do you want also to scan the workbook that this code is in ? And is this workbook in the same folder as all the others ?

Comment: No, I want to search for the given input across all workbooks in my directory, when sheet names match just two or three.

Comment: What I meant was if you open all the workbooks in turn in that directory will you also be reopening the workbook that this code is in ?

Comment: No. I have a separate workbook, which picks up all workbooks in the given directory by the code. But instead of searching values between all worksheets in all these workbooks, I just need to search these values between 3 worksheets defined by the name, which is the same across all workbooks in this directory.

Comment: `Set xOut = Worksheets("SUMMARY")` which workbook is this?  The one with the code?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `On Error` line?

Comment: Let me understand this. Is this what you are trying? **1.** Select a folder **2.** Loop though all Excel files in that folder. **3.** Search for the BoM Code **4.** Search only Sheets `Civils Work Order` and `Cable Works Order` **5.** Update Summary sheet with the results?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Alternatively, I could add also another sheet to search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit lengthy, but a lot of the bulk is re-useable functions, so it lets you focus on the logic in the main method.

I'm guessing that the summary sheet is in the same workbook as this code, and that you're scanning a folder for files to summarize, one of which may already be open in Excel (so you don't want to open that again).

Compiles but not tested...

```vb
Sub SearchFolders()

    Dim wbAct As Workbook, pathMainWb As String, fldrPath As String
    Dim bom As String, scrUpdt, wsOut As Worksheet, colFiles As Collection, f As Object
    Dim xBol As Boolean, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, arrWs
    Dim matchedCells As Collection, cell, numHits As Long, summRow As Long
    
    Set wbAct = ActiveWorkbook
    pathMainWb = wbAct.FullName '<<<<
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    fldrPath = UserSelectFolder("Select a folder")
    If Len(fldrPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    'get all files in the selected folder
    Set colFiles = GetFileMatches(fldrPath, "*.xls*", False) 'False=no subfolders
    If colFiles.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Excel files found in selected folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    bom = InputBox("Please provide the BoM Code")
    
    scrUpdt = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY")
    
    summRow = 1
    'sheet names to scan
    arrWs = Array("Civils Job Order", "Civils Work Order", "Cable Works Order")
    
    wsOut.Cells(summRow, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array("Workbook", "Worksheet", _
                        "Cell", "Text in Cell", "Values corresponding")
    For Each f In colFiles
        xBol = (f.Path = pathMainWb)  'file already open? 
        If xBol Then
            Set wb = wbAct
        Else
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=f.Path, UpdateLinks:=0, _
                                     ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
        End If
        
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            'are we interested in this sheet?
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, arrWs, 0)) Then
                Set matchedCells = FindAll(ws.UsedRange, bom) 'get all cells with bom
                If matchedCells.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each cell In matchedCells
                        summRow = summRow + 1
                        wsOut.Cells(summRow, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = _
                            Array(wb.Name, ws.Name, cell.Address, cell.Value, _
                                    cell.EntireRow.Range("F1").Value)
                    
                        numHits = numHits + 1
                    Next cell     'next match
                End If            'any bom matches
            End If                'matched sheet name
        Next ws
        If Not xBol Then wb.Close False 'need to close this workbook?
    Next f
    
    wsOut.Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
    MsgBox numHits & " cells have been found", , "BoM Calculator for VM Greenfield"

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = scrUpdt
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub

'ask the user to select a folder
Function UserSelectFolder(msgPrompt As String) As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = msgPrompt
        If .Show = -1 Then UserSelectFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
End Function

'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetFileMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr, fpath
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder
    
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        
        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1
        
        If subFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            Next subFldr
        End If
        
        fpath = fldr.Path
        If Right(fpath, 1) <> "\" Then fpath = fpath & "\"
        f = Dir(fpath & filePattern) 'Dir is faster...
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            colFiles.Add fso.getfile(fpath & f)
            f = Dir()
        Loop
    Loop
    Set GetFileMatches = colFiles
End Function

'search range `rng` for all matches to `val` and return
'   as a Collection of ranges (cells)
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Ah you beat me :D I also was using `re-useable procedures`. I guess I will abort it!

Comment: I'm sure yours is neater...

Comment: This code looks quite different from the original one. Does it mean, that it had to be necessary to rebuilt it?

Comment: Not "necessary" but maybe a "good idea"  - your original code has a singe method (sub) with "does too much" - it's good practice to try to parse out specific functions like "pick a folder", "find all Excel files in a folder", and "find all cells in a range with this value".  There are a few advantages of this approach, such (1) you can more-easily test the separate functions (2) you can re-use the separate functions in later code

Comment: ... (3) with the other function pulled out of your main code, now you can focus on the core of your logic, instead of having everything else mixed up in there (loops for finding files, loops for finding cells, etc).     Plus I'm not a fan of using an "x" prefix for all your variables so I can't help but "fix" that.